# Updating Class Variable with a Process (Python)

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a question regarding threading and class variables in a python program I am writing.

I have a class that keeps a list of instances in a class variable. I have a process that makes instances of this class. When the process finishes running, the class variable listing instances of the class is always empty.

A minimal reproducible example of my problem is as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

class C(object):
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        C.instances.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return(f"{self.name}")

def init():
    names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
    for n in names:
        C(n)

Process(target=init).start()
print(C.instances)
```

Actual Output: `[]`

Expected Output: `[a, b, c, d, e]`

I have tried joining and closing the thread before printing the instances, but the same output is given. I did eventually manage to get the expected output, but I had to make an extra class to track the instances and pass an object of it in and out of the process through a queue.

The best guess I can come up with is that the process duplicates the class in such a way that the class variables inside and outside the process are no longer in the same scope and the process's copy of the class is discarded when the process finishes, leaving the class variable effectively unchanged.

What is the appropriate way to do what I am trying to do? Please tell me if there is any more information I should provide and thank you for your help.

Comment: Every process has its own copy of variables. You should use threads if you want variables to be shared by them.

Comment: You would also have to join the process to make sure its finished executing before checking the variable. But still, those changes were in the newly created process space, not your process - so there is nothing to see. You can setup communication between the created process and its parent, but there are many ways to do that and you have some design decisions to make.

Comment: What do you really need to know about the class objects created in the new process? `C.instances.append(self)` just adds a pointer to the object to the class list, which doesn't help much in the parent process. Do you want to be able to interact with those objects? Then some sort of an IPC like `rpcxml`. Do you want some resultant value? Then maybe something like `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't know there was a difference between `multiprocessing.Process` and `threading.Thread`, I thought Process replaced Thread with Python3. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @tdelaney, thanks for your comment! I solved the problem by using threads instead. I didn't know processes were isolated and thought they were the same as threads. You are right though, joining and closing the thread didn't make a difference. The only way I could find to do it with processes was to pass a class back and forth to the subprocess using a queue.

Comment: @tdelaney, the larger picture of what I am trying to do is show the status of all the instances of the class when an event is published, and the easiest way to do that I thought would be to just import the class and call a class method that prints all the instances and relevant attributes.